# Only two parallel https calls are going outside with SSLConnectionSocketFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

When I I am making outgoing requests with SSLConnectionSocketFactory request factory, only two parallel outgoing calls are getting response at a time. Subsequent calls reaches outside endpoint only when first two requests finish responding.

This is the RestTemplate config,

```
private RestTemplate createSSLRestTemplate(String keyStorePath, String keyStorePassword) throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(new ClassPathResource(keyStorePath).getInputStream(), keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            new SSLContextBuilder()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                    .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray())
                    .build(),
            NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(
            socketFactory).build();

    ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
            httpClient);
    BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory bufferingRequestFactory = new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(bufferingRequestFactory);
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(restTemplateLoggingInterceptor));
    return restTemplate;
}
```

However if I replaced the RestTemplate with simple RestTeamplate all the calls goes to outside and responds in parallel.

```
public RestTemplate restTemplateDefault() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

Code that make the outgoing http request

```
HttpEntity<Req> request = new HttpEntity(req, this.prepareHttpHeaders());
        return this.xmlUnmarshaller.unmarshall((String)this.restTemplate.postForObject(host, request, String.class, new Object[0]), responseClass);
```

How do I have sslcontext and have achieve parallelism?